# does bash promise to optimize -c into plain exec in simple cases?

Tags: bash, shell, process, sh, pid

Consider the following invocation of bash

```
bash -c 'sleep 99'
```

Suppose I run that, and while waiting for it to finish sleeping, I run `ps` in another terminal.  In that case, I do indeed find `sleep 99` running.  But its parent is NOT a process running `bash -c`.  Instead, its parent is the process that INVOKED `bash -c`.  I can think of only one explanation for this: bash noticed that since it's being asked to run a simple command, it permored the "optimized" sequence of `exec sleep 99` instead of the "obvious" sequence of `fork; exec sleep 99; wait; exit`.

The reason I ask is that I noticed today that at work we have some Python scripts that very much depend on this behavior.  (It wasn't obvious at first; we were using `subprocess` with `shell=True`... I didn't realize the implications until now.)  I was trying to port them to windows and of course `cmd.exe` doesn't do this because `exec` is not traditionally a thing on Windows.

Then I wondered... is it actually documented anywhere that bash does this?  I'd be quite surprised if it turns out that POSIX mandates this.  I see no mention of it in the bash user manual.  (Though it's a big manual.)  Any idea to what extend this is guaranteed?

Comment: This is not POSIX-guaranteed, and such optimisations are implementation-defined. Here's a cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466496/why-is-there-no-apparent-clone-or-fork-in-simple-bash-command-and-how-its-done

Comment: It's a compile-time option: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/config-top.h#L39

Comment: To be honest I think this subshell micro-optomization of Bash which "promotes" "returning" function values through command substitution practice ruins bash and invites a lot of bugs. It's better if it just adds a feature that avoids command substitution. This thread's problem isn't exactly about command substitution calls of course but it's part of the family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we have some Python scripts that [...] were using `subprocess` with `shell=True`

Note that on UNIX-y systems, such as Linux or Mac, that will not launch Bash *per se*.  Rather, it will launch `/bin/sh`.  That might or might not be Bash (even on Linux), and if it *is* Bash then Bash runs in POSIX mode when launched by that name.

> is it actually documented anywhere that bash does this? [...] I see no mention of it in the bash user manual.

I feel confident that my study of [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) was sufficient to support my affirmation that no, such behavior is not documented there.  Nor is it in the manual page.  I pretty much expect a mention in the source code, but that would be developer-facing, not user-facing.

> Any idea to what extend this is guaranteed?

There being no user documentation of this behavior, the best answer is probably "not at all".  Of course, Bash is software, so if you observe such behavior in one case, you should be able to rely on the same in sufficiently similar cases, but it's hard to characterize "sufficiently similar" very precisely.

In the case of your Python scripts, if you are in fact relying on Bash to directly `exec` the specified command, then you should strongly consider not specifying `shell=True`. But do bear in mind that ensuring that there is no interposing shell is not the only effect of doing so.  The usual reason for `shell=True` is in fact that you want to use shell features, such as I/O redirection, in the command.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original author of the scripts even realized they were depending on this.  I've been here for years and only realized it when I tried to port to a shell that doesn't do this.

Comment: @MarkVY, if I were to make a wild guess, I would say that the main reason why your scripts use `shell=True` is probably to get the shell to perform word-splitting on the command, as opposed to doing that manually on the Python side.  You now pay for that shortcut, because reliably getting rid of the intervening shell is going to require you to do that manual splitting.  Which is what the docs recommend doing anyway, so there's that.

Comment: Well, in some cases we use compound commands, so we need `shell=True` there... probably used it everywhere for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(Personally I hate this *smart* feature.)</sup>

If you want the behavior:

```
bash -c 'exec sleep 99'
  sh -c 'exec sleep 99'
```

If you want to avoid the behavior:

```
bash -c 'sleep 99; exit'
  sh -c 'sleep 99; exit'
```